# Filter array matching all object keys. Get new array with unique objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to get 2 new arrays based on an existing array containing objects. (keys stay the same for each object)

newArray1 objects should be unique in terms of their value. In other words:

```
[ 
   {Layer:"Layer",LayerName:"foo",LayerWidth:200,LayerHeight:400},
   {Layer:"Layer",LayerName:"FOOBAR",LayerWidth:200,LayerHeight:400},       
   {Layer:"Layer",LayerName:"foo",LayerWidth:200,LayerHeight:400}
]
```

- newArray1 should consist of 1st and 2nd object, because 3rd has the same object-values like the 1st object.
- newArray2 should contain all other objects, that are not in newArray1, (3rd object only)

```js
arr = []

for(var i=0;i<allSymbols.length;i++){
    var obj={
      Layer: allSymbols(i),
      LayerName: allSymbols(i).name(),
      LayerWidth: allSymbols(i).width(),
      LayerHeight: allSymbols(i).height()
    }
    arr.push(obj)
}


// filter so far... 
for(var u=0;u<arr.length;u++){
    var filter = arr[u];
    arr = arr.filter(function(item){
     for(var key in filter){
       if(item[key] == filter[key]){
        return true
       }
     }
       return false
    });
}

// output newArray1(arr)?
// output newArray2?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

#### Logic

- Get filtered list for every object.
- Get index of first matching object.
- If length of filtered list is one, object is unique and should be pushed to unique list.
- If not and if index is equal to current index, this is the first occurrence and again should be pushed to unique list.
- For all remaining objects, they are duplicates and are second or nth repetition and should be pushed to duplicate list

```js
var d = [{Layer:"Layer",LayerName:"foo",LayerWidth:200,LayerHeight:400},{Layer:"Layer",LayerName:"FOOBAR",LayerWidth:200,LayerHeight:400},{Layer:"Layer",LayerName:"foo",LayerWidth:200,LayerHeight:400}]

var dupes = [];
var unique = [];

d.forEach(function(c,i,a){
  var objStr = JSON.stringify(c);
  
  var index = a.findIndex(function(o){
    return JSON.stringify(o) === objStr;
  });
  
  var _filter = a.filter(function(o){
    return JSON.stringify(o) === objStr;
  });
  if(_filter.length === 1 || index === i){
    unique.push(c)
  } 
  else{
    dupes.push(c);
  }
}, []);

console.log(dupes, unique)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check for duplicate objects and filter the given data.

```js
var data = [{ Layer: "Layer", LayerName: "foo", LayerWidth: 200, LayerHeight: 400 }, { Layer: "Layer", LayerName: "FOOBAR", LayerWidth: 200, LayerHeight: 400 }, { Layer: "Layer", LayerName: "foo", LayerWidth: 200, LayerHeight: 400 }],
    array1 = [],
    array2 = data.filter(function (a) {
        return array1.some(function (b) {
            return Object.keys(a).length === Object.keys(b).length && Object.keys(a).every(function (k) {
                return a[k] === b[k];
            });
        }) || array1.push(a) && false;
    });

console.log(array1);
console.log(array2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```